# How to change the color of the active tab in Mac's Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to change the active tab color in Mac's terminal? I've tried messing around with the colors in the profile but I can't figure out a way to change the actual color of the tab. It's driving me insane that the active color is a lighter color than the inactive tabs, which is inconsistent with basically every other program that uses tabs.

I'm using Catalina 10.15.2 with Terminal Version 2.10 (433).

[Picture of Terminal tab colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DjwK.png)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your terminal(s) to demonstrate your issues with the colours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. As I'm sure you probably know, you can change the profile which includes font, background etc... but the tab itself cannot be changed. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the active tab colour. But if what you want is to have better contrast between the active and inactive tabs, you can set the 'Tab color' in Profiles - Colors.

Comment: I can't see this setting - can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't do it with the default terminal.  ITerm2 provides the capability (which does help because the difference between active and inactive gets a bit confusing on dark mode)